# Do I need to encrypt my passwordeditfield before sending over the internet

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I know that the  PasswordEditField displays asterisks but stores in plain text, and I also know that the Blackberry network is encrypted.

If I am using BIS, do I need to encrypt the value in the PasswordEditField before posting over the Internet to a web service?

If the client states that encryption is required, Can I simply to the encryption/decryption at the backend, but send plain text over the Internet (under the cover of RIM's encryption)?

Comment: http://us.blackberry.com/ataglance/security/features.jsp It does to encryption, but only to a Blackberry(tm) Enterprise(tm) Server(tm). Is that what you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're making an HTTP connection to a web service, you need to do your own encryption. BIS can protect communication internally, but eventually it has to go over the open Internet to get to the web service. At that point, the information is vulnerable.

If you connect via HTTPS, then the entire communication channel is encrypted and you don't need to do any additional encryption.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the rapid response.  I am in the middle of coding with 2 days to delivery.  It is nice to know I can access this kind of support.  Kudos to all.

Answer (score 1):

This link suggests that not everything between the Blackberry and the BES is encrypted (http://www.blackberryforums.com/bes-admin-corner/162794-blackberry-encryption-question.html).

However, IIRC, you can initiate an SSL connection between the device and your server.
Ah - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Support-for-HTTPS-connection/ta-p/445952 - shows example of encrypted connections.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed BIS was a typo.  Just looked up BIS.